# Failed to get response for large file HTTP put create file using c#

Tags: c#, webrequest

Failed to get response for large file HTTP put create file using c#

I am using file watcher service service monitor, when user created file or folder we are uploading to cloud

if file size more than 512 MB it is taking too much time to get the response

here I am confusing here the issue with my code or server

and reason for this error

if any changes on my code suggest me.

```
{
    var fileFolderObj1 = new FileFolder();
    var postURL = apiBaseUri + "/filefolder/create/file/user/" + userId; // +"?type=file";
    code = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
    long filesizeF = f.Length;

    try
    {
        string selectedFile = null;
        selectedFile = filePath;
        var fi = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);            

        ////commented for some reason
        var postParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        postParameters.Add("file", new FileParameter(filePath,  ""));
        postParameters.Add("parentId", parentId);
        postParameters.Add("newName", fi);
        postParameters.Add("cloudId", cloudId);
        postParameters.Add("isSecure", isSecure);
        //postParameters.Add("fileSize", fi.Length);
        postParameters.Add("fileSize", filesizeF);

        var userAgent = "Desktop";
        var formDataBoundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

        var uri = new Uri(postURL);
        var createFileRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        this.SetBasicAuthHeader(createFileRequest, userId, password);
        createFileRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        createFileRequest.Method = "PUT";
        createFileRequest.Timeout =  System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
        createFileRequest.KeepAlive = false;/*true;*/
        createFileRequest.UserAgent = userAgent;
        createFileRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        try
        {
            using (var requestStream = createFileRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {        
            }

            using (response = (HttpWebResponse)createFileRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(); 
                fileFolderObj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileFolder>(reslut);
            }                   
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {                    
            if (response != null)
            {
                code = response.StatusCode;
            }
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {                
    }
}       
}

    private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    private void WriteMultipartFormData(Dictionary<string, object> postParameters, string boundary, Stream requestStream, ILogService logService = null)
    { 
        var needsCLRF = false;
        foreach (var param in postParameters)
        {
            // Skip it on the first parameter, add it to subsequent parameters.
            if (needsCLRF)
            {
                requestStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("\r\n"), 0, encoding.GetByteCount("\r\n"));
            }
            needsCLRF = true;
            if (param.Value is FileParameter)
            {
                var fileToUpload = (FileParameter)param.Value;
                // Add just the first part of this param, since we will write the file data directly to the Stream
                var header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\"\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.FileName ?? param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.ContentType ?? "application/octet-stream");

                requestStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(header), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(header));
                // Write the file data directly to the Stream, rather than serializing it to a string.
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileToUpload.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0,buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    logService.Debug("WRITEMULTIPART FORM DATA Bufferlent Running :{0}", bytesRead);
                }
                fileStream.Close();


            }
            else
            {
                var postData = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    param.Value);
                requestStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(postData));
            }
        }

        // Add the end of the request.  Start with a newline
        var footer = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";

        requestStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(footer), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(footer));

    }
}
```

Comment: what are your timeouts set to?

Comment: can you please explain more about ur question @bugFinder

Comment: What do you mean with `OR file is di`?

Comment: sorry that is json object